# Update/insert records from a table to same table based on some criteria

Tags: sql-server

i have a table like below where **pid** and **srno** are part of **primary key**.

```
PID     | Srno | coverType | UID | HTID | PTID | PCID | AreaSqFeet
------------------------------------------------------------------
P00001  | 1    |   01      | 01  |  1   |  1   |  1   |   450
P00001  | 2    |   02      | 01  |  1   |  1   |  1   |   250
P00002  | 1    |   01      | 01  |  1   |  1   |  1   |   750
P00002  | 2    |   02      | 02  |  2   |  3   |  5   |   450
```

when coverType,UID,HTID,PTID,PCID of both PID's are same(all should match),then add AreaSqFeet of both PID's and update it in PID 'P00001'
and insert the P00002 record if coverType,UID,HTID,PTID,PCID do not match(anyone is not matching) like below

```
P00001  | 3    |   02      | 02  |  2   |  3   |  5   |   450
```

final output should be like below

```
PID     | Srno | coverType | UID | HTID | PTID | PCID | AreaSqFeet
------------------------------------------------------------------
P00001  | 1    |   01      | 01  |  1   |  1   |  1   |   1200
P00001  | 2    |   02      | 01  |  1   |  1   |  1   |   250
P00001  | 3    |   02      | 02  |  2   |  3   |  5   |   450
```

Please suggest how to achieve above result.

hope i'm able to explain my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, in which language are you expecting an answer ? SQL ?  why do you expect to update the same table ? what is data flow / processing around that use case ?
Do you mean SUM of AreaSqFeet  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the requirement correct, following code could resolve your problem:

```
declare @tab table (PID varchar(100),Srno int, coverType varchar(10), UID varchar(10), HTID int, PTID int, PCID int, AreaSqFeet int)
insert into @tab select 'P00001'  , 1    ,   '01'      , '01'  ,  1   ,  1   ,  1   ,   450
insert into @tab select 'P00001'  , 2    ,   '02'      , '01'  ,  1   ,  1   ,  1   ,   250
insert into @tab select 'P00002'  , 1    ,   '01'      , '01'  ,  1   ,  1   ,  1   ,   750
insert into @tab select 'P00002'  , 2    ,   '02'      , '02'  ,  2   ,  3   ,  5   ,   450

drop table if exists #temp
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by pid, srno) as rn into #temp
from @tab

delete @tab
select * from #temp

declare @PID varchar(100), @coverType varchar(100), @UID varchar(100), @HTID int, @PTID int, @PCID int, @AreaSqFeet int
declare @max_srno int
declare cur cursor fast_forward for select PID, coverType, UID, HTID, PTID, PCID, AreaSqFeet from #temp
open cur
fetch next from cur into @PID, @coverType, @UID, @HTID, @PTID, @PCID, @AreaSqFeet
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @max_srno = (select isnull(max(Srno), 0) from @tab)

    if((select count(1) from @tab ft
        join (select  @PID PID, @coverType coverType, @UID UID, @HTID HTID, @PTID PTID, @PCID PCID, @AreaSqFeet AreaSqFeet) t 
            on t.coverType = ft.coverType and ft.UID = t.UID and ft.HTID = t.HTID and ft.PTID = t.PTID and ft.PCID = t.PCID) > 0)
    begin
        update ft
        set AreaSqFeet = AreaSqFeet+@AreaSqFeet
        from @tab ft
        where ft.coverType = @coverType and ft.UID = @UID and ft.HTID = @HTID and ft.PTID = @PTID and ft.PCID = @PCID
    end
    else
        insert into @tab
        select 'P00001', @max_srno+1, @coverType, @UID, @HTID, @PTID, @PCID, @AreaSqFeet

    fetch next from cur into @PID, @coverType, @UID, @HTID, @PTID, @PCID, @AreaSqFeet
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a61f6cf2742cdef06e6ab92a5ecc3fb8)**.